# Collection for storing elements such as key-value-value

Tags: java, collections

Which collection can be used to store items, such as key-value-value ? For example i need something like this:

```
  elements.add (0, "first", 1);
  elements.add(1, "second", 2);
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: But well: https://dzone.com/articles/hashmap-%E2%80%93-single-key-and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a class `Triple` which will take three parameters.

```
public class Triple<K, V1, V2> {

  private K key;
  private V1 value1;
  private V2 value2;

  public Triple(K a, V1 value1, V2 value2) {
    this.key = a;
    this.value1 = value1;
    this.value2 = value2;
  }

  public K getKey() {
    return key;
  }

  public V1 getValue1() {
    return value1;
  }

  public V2 getValue2() {
    return value2;
  }
}
```

Then add another class `TripleList` which will serve as a collection where you can add instances of `Triple`:

```
  public  class TripleList<K, V1, V2> implements Iterable<Triple<K, V1, V2>> {

    private List<Triple<K, V1, V2>> triples = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(K key, V1 value1, V2 value2) {
      triples.add(new Triple<>(key, value1, value2));
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Triple<K, V1, V2>> iterator() {
      return triples.iterator();
    }
  }
```

Using them you can do the following:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Triple<Integer, String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Triple<Integer, String, Integer>(0, "first", 1));
    list.add(new Triple<Integer, String, Integer>(1, "second", 2));

    TripleList<Integer, String, Integer> elements = new TripleList<>();
    elements.add(0, "first", 1);
    elements.add(1, "second", 2);

    for (Triple<Integer, String, Integer> triple : elements) {
       System.out.println(triple.getKey() + "," + triple.getValue1() + "," + triple.getValue2());  
    }
  }
```

You asked for a `Collection`. `TripleList` isn't actually a `Collection` as it doesn't implement `Collection`. But this should be possible by delegating to the methods of the inner list `triples`.

Answer (score 4):

You should define your own class to define a value and use `Map<Integer, MyValue>` as overall structure.

Example :

```
public class MyValue{
    public MyValue(String string, int i){
       ...
    }
}
```

And use it :

```
Map<Integer, MyValue> elements = new HashMap<>();
elements.put(0, new MyValue("first", 1));
```

You have as alternative a `List` as value but a generic `List` relies on a specific type such as `List<String>` or `List<Integer>`. So in your case I would avoid this way as you mix types in the values.

You have also other alternatives that don't require to introduce custom classes but in general this is often not clear for people that have to read/maintain code : `javafx.util.Pair<K,V>` or `java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<K, V>` are example of them.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using JDK9

```
Map<Integer,Map.Entry<String,Integer>> map=new HashMap<>();
```

Now you can create Map.Entry using static method entry(K k,V v) in Map interface 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-

Life will be fun now for java programmers to return two values from a method using   `return Map.entry("firstValue","secondValue");`